# Spark Read multiple paths with automatic partitions discovery

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-avro

I'm trying to read some avro files to a DataFrame from multiple path.
Let's say my path is `"s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=01"`
Under this path I have two more partitions let's say `country=XX/region=XX`

I want to read multiple dates at once without explicitly name country and region partitions. In addition I want country and region to be columns in this DataFrame.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=01")
```

This line works perfectly well since I only read one path. It detects country and region partitions and infer their schema.

When I trying to read multiple dates let's say

```
val paths = Seq("s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=01", "s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=02")

sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths:_*)
```

I get this error:

```
    18/12/03 03:13:53 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result insub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
18/12/03 03:13:53 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths:?
 s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=02
s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/year=18/month=11/day=01
    
If provided paths are partition directories, please set "basePath" in the options of the data source to specify the root directory of the table. If there are multiple root directories, please load them separately and then union them.
        at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.parsePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$HadoopFsRelation$$discoverPartitions(interfaces.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$partitionSpec$3.apply(interfaces.scala:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$partitionSpec$3.apply(interfaces.scala:525)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.partitionSpec(interfaces.scala:524)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$partitionColumns$1.apply(interfaces.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$partitionColumns$1.apply(interfaces.scala:578)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.partitionColumns(interfaces.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:637)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:136)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:25)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at <init>(<console>:44)
        at .<init>(<console>:48)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Obviosly I can't use basePath because the paths don't share one. I also try to use /* in the end of each path, this actually works but ignores completely country and region partitions.

I can read the path one by one and union it, but I feel like I missing something.

Any idea why it's working only for a single path and how to make it work for multiple paths?

Answer (score 2):

Really wish all error messages would be as clear - `If provided paths are partition directories, please set "basePath" in the options of the data source to specify the root directory of the table. If there are multiple root directories, please load them separately and then union them.`

Does the relative path `year=18/month=11/day=01` is due to partitioning, or did you just used the same convention?

If the former is correct, then you should just read `s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/`, and use predicates to filter desired dates. Or maybe as suggested by the error, you could try `sqlContext.read.option("basePath","s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file/").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths:_*)`, where paths are relative

If the latter is true, then you should query each separately and apply `unionAll` on dataframes (as error message suggests). Perhaps treating the year/month/day as partition columns would work as well in this case, even though you didn't use partitionBy when you wrote the data...

Comment: Since I want to read in windows and every time different set of dates I don't want to use only the basePath. I can read it send a list of dates in some format and filter I also can read path by path and unionAll I mentioned it specifically in my initial question. What I don't understand is why it's working for a single path and not multiple paths. I can't understand what is the difference. If it's not possible I cant do one of these options.

Comment: Assertion is related to following tickets about partition discovery - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11678 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10304. I guess that if you didn't use same conventions as used by spark for partition discovery, it wouldn't throw this exception...

Comment: "I guess that if you didn't use same conventions as used by spark for partition discovery, it wouldn't throw this exception" Yeah I know, still I don't get why partition discovery will work on one path and not on multiple paths. I do want to keep the spark convention for partition. If no one can answer it I don't understand why people down vote a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but this is what I ended up doing in a similar situation

```
spark.read.parquet(paths:_*)
  .withColumn("year", regexp_extract(input_file_name, "year=(.+?)/", 1))
  .withColumn("month", regexp_extract(input_file_name, "month=(.+?)/", 1))
  .withColumn("day", regexp_extract(input_file_name, "day=(.+?)/", 1))
```

Works when you have a static partition structure. Who's up to challenge to extend it to dynamic (i.e. to parse out arbitrary partition structure of the form 'x=y/z=c' and convert it to columns)?